# How to center Text in div with floating button without offsetting text?

Tags: html, css

How does one center text within a div and also have a button floating to the right without pushing the text over to the left?

We've already tried centering it but the best we could come up with was an approximate relative percentage. This doesn't scale well, but works at our typical screen resolution.

```html
<div>
  <span style="position: absolute; left: 43%;">Text</span>
  <button style="float:right">Button</button>
</div>
```

The following image is the ideal way we'd like to to look, and we're hoping there is a way to achieve this without using a strange percentage like 43% since this doesn't work perfectly the larger the screen gets.
[image: Centered text with floating button to the right]

Comment: You have 3 options now :) Please accept an answer and therefore close the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixing elements is good way, but once you start fixing, you will never end. Instead I strongly recommend to you to learn a little bit about [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

In your case, I'd divide the screen into 3 parts and then I could accomodate as I need all objects. It is more complicated when you are getting started, but once you are used to working with flex-box you will find it easy.

Take a look at this way:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-div, 
.right-div {
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.right-div{
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.center-div {
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  margin-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-div"></div>
  <div class="center-div">
    <span>Text</span>  
  </div>
  <div class="right-div">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While I agree with the recommendation to learn Flexbox, using random percentages is a messy approach because there a bunch of cases where those percentages may need to be fiddled: e.g. when changing the text content, changing the button text, or for internationalization. Also, adding a left div with nothing in it is unnecessary. In this case, simplicity is your friend, and Tim's answer is best here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41749949/1101602.

Answer (score 4):

You could always position the button `absolute`, like this;

```html
<div style="text-align:center; position:relative;">
  <span>Text</span>
  <button style="position:absolute; right:10px;">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can edit the html, you could try this one:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 50%;
}

.left {
  position: relative; 
  left: -50%;
}

.right {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">Text</div>
  </div>
    
  <button class="right">Button</button>
</div>
```